# ListVIew personalizado não está aparecendo

Tags: android

Estou tentando criar um ListView personalizado. Em outro projeto criei um xml row_cliente e no ListView coloquei `tools:listitem="@layout/row_cliente"`, porém ele não aparace minha lista personalizada e sim a lista padrão. Alguém sabe o porque disso ?

ListView Personalizado:

[image: ListView Personalizado]
ListView Padrão:

[image: ListView Normal]
Código ListView:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listViewCliente"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:listitem="@layout/row_cliente">
```

Código do row_cliente

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:paddingLeft="100dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
```

Comment: Poste o layout e o código fonte para contextualizar melhor a pergunta.

Comment: Você ta usando BaseAdapter ou um adapter customizado? Pode estar nele o problema